# docker.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing

Tags: docker, systemctl

My VM crashed because it was out of memory. After rebooting the machine docker was not running:

```
systemctl status docker
● docker.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Dec 19 08:18:21 my-vm-single-instance systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/docker.service:1] Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Dec 19 08:18:21 my-vm-single-instance systemd[1]: docker.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

I installed docker using the offical documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/

The VM is running:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Docker version 19.03.14, build 5eb3275d40
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
```

I got docker up and running again with

```
dockerd
```

However I would like to get it running again through systemctl.

The contents of `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` are:

```
Environment="GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/etc/docker/key.json"
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `docker.service` contains only one line as it mentioned it's bogus.
As it says

```
docker.service: Service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.
```

the executions scripts are missing at least.

Here is a sample service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target firewalld.service containerd.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket containerd.service

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not support it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this option.
TasksMax=infinity

# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process
OOMScoreAdjust=-500

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my default service file. I've never modified it after installation.